# generic class with superclass

Tags: c#, generics, superclass

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //GrandFather gf = new Son();
        IGF<Father> igf = new MyClass();
    }
}
public class Father
{

}
public class Son : Father
{
}
public class MyClass : IGF<Son>
{
    public void Method()
    {
        //DoSomething
    }
}
public interface IGF<T> where T : Father
{
    void Method();
}
```

Hello everyone,I meet a question when I using generic class with superclass.
Can anyone tell me that why line 6 is wrong ,as when we using list,we always say that IList ss=new List();

Comment: Your inheritance chain is weird. Think of a class derived from a base class as an "is-a" relationship. So you're saying that a `Son` is-a `Father`, which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using C# 4.0, you can add the `out` keyword to the `IGF` implementation to make it a [covariant interface](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx).  This allows you to have a generic with a base class (here `Father`) and have it point to an instance of that same interface with a derived generic type (`Son`).